# Cant make a txt output at proper format

Tags: python, dictionary, subset, subset-sum

This is my code. The problem is that the output looks like this

`2015-06-03 19:32:11.225085
{'2015-01-21-20:56:45.mp3': 1}{'negative': -2}{'2015-01-15-21:28:23.mp3': 1}`

i want to be like a dictionary.... like this one below so i can read it back as a dictionary and remove the keys from the first subset sum and go on output a second on and so on until no other subset sum exists...

`2015-06-03 19:32:11.225085
{'2015-01-21-20:56:45.mp3': 1, 'negative': -2, '2015-01-15-21:28:23.mp3': 1}`

Any ideas?

thanx in advanced

```
import os, sys,re,gzip, pickle 
from itertools import combinations
import json
from datetime import datetime
mp3folder = raw_input('Please copy paste the mp3s path:')
lowerin = input('Please enter your total playlist time in NEGATIVE seconds and hit ENTER:')
r = {}
drk = os.listdir(mp3folder) 
drifiles = list(drk)
r = dict.fromkeys(drifiles, 0)
for key in r.keys():

        print ('Please enter the duration of...')
        print(key)
        r[key] = input('in seconds and hit ENTER:')

r['negative'] = lowerin
d = {}
neg = 0
pos = 0
dates = datetime.now()
dates = str(dates)
f = open("dict.txt",'ab')
f.write('\n'+dates+'\n')
f.close()
for (w,v) in r.iteritems():
        if v > 0: pos += v
        else:     neg += v

sums = [0] * (pos - neg + 1)

for (w,v) in r.iteritems():
        s = sums[:]
        if not s[v - neg]: s[v - neg] = (w,)

        for (i, w2) in enumerate(sums):
                if w2 and not s[i + v]:
                        s[i + v] = w2 + (w,)

        sums = s
        if s[-neg]:
                for x in s[-neg]:

                        d = dict([(x, r[x])])
                        file('dict.txt','a'+'\n').write(repr(d))


                break
```

Comment: Please don't downvote and not tell why! That is rude

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('dict.txt','r')
filedata = f.read()
f.close()

newdata = filedata.replace("}{",", ")

f = open('lexiko.txt','w')
f.write(newdata)
f.close()

di = eval(open("lexiko.txt").read())

print di
```

this will do it